# IntelliJ Content root resets after closing Project

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a simple project with 1 module in IntelliJ. I go to `File -> Project Structure -> Module -> Add Content Root` and set the root of the project folder to be the project root, but after I close the project, or quit IntelliJ and open the project again, the content root is not set.

IntelliJ Community v2020.2

MacOSX Big Sur 11.0.1

Answer (score 3):

I fix it by:

1. quit IntelliJ
2. delete .idea file in the folder
3. open the project again

Comment: Worked for me. To whoever is facing this issue: try this step before modifying your project structure.